# What are the layers included by default in a Mapbox map?

Tags: gis, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I cannot find any documentation on what layers are included by default in a Mapbox map?

I know `water` is one, since you can place a layer you add before it (see documentation [here](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/geojson-layer-in-stack/)), but what are the other "default" layers?

Answer (score -1):

The layers on the map are determined by the map's style.

You can see the layers in a style by

- opening the style in [Mapbox Studio](https://www.mapbox.com/studio/)
- using the [`Map#getStyle`](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/api/#map#getstyle) method
- looking at the style JSON in the [`mapbox-gl-styles` Github repo](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-styles) (only applicable to basic, bright, empty, and satellite)